# Deployment with Capistrano giving error for Pg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano, pg

When I try to Deploy my application with Capistrano, it gives error

> An error occurred while installing pg (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot
>   continue.
>
> Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.

I've already installed pg version 1.0.0 and its pre-requisite dependencies.

What other changes need to be made in order to overcome with issue?

Comment: Are there any more specific errors within the stacktrace?
Did you install the gem for another ruby version before?

Comment: I am having only single ruby version installed on server and that is ruby-2.4.0

Answer (score 2):

I setup a capistrano task to bundle config the pg_config location:

`namespace :bundler do
  before 'bundler:install', :config
    desc 'bundle config options'
    task :config do
      on roles(:all), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Required for pg gem to be installed
      execute 'bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_config'
    end
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

When Capistrano runs bundler, it specifies a configuration that installs the gems in a location that is separate from your global gems location. That means that even if you had run `gem install pg` successfully before, bundler will still need to do it again when you `cap deploy`.

To figure out why bundler is failing, you could try a few different standard Capistrano troubleshooting techniques:

1. Check the Capistrano console output or `log/capistrano.log` for details on what went wrong. Bundler will sometimes point you to a temporary file where the results of the gem install process were recorded, and you can look there as well.
2. SSH into your server, change into the failed release directory, and manually run the bundler command that is failing. See if this provides more information. Make sure to enter the bundler command exactly as you see it in `log/caipstrano.log` (although I suggest removing the `--quiet` flag). It typically looks like:

   ```
   bundle install --deployment --without development test --path /path/to/shared/bundle
   ```
3. Capistrano uses a non-login shell, so things like `$PATH` may be different when Capistrano runs bundler vs when you run it interactively. Those differences could cause bundler to succeed in one environment but fail in the other. You can write a task like this inspect the environment that Capistrano sees:

   ```
   # Add this to deploy.rb and then run `cap production env`
   task :env do
     on roles(:all) do
       puts capture("env")
     end
   end
   ```

Refer to this explanation of Capistrano's environment: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/

Comment: I checked by moving into my server, I am unable to install pg,when I install pg with command  gem install pg -v '1.0.0' it installs but when I do bundle install and it fails and give me error "Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.". I already have installed its pre library with "sudo apt-get install libpq-dev" but still having error.

Comment: I am having this error:
current directory: /home/root/apps/adminapp1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/pg-1.0.0/ext
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180322-19885-xykhcg.rb extconf.rb
--with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/0.21.0/bin/pg_config
Using config values from /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/0.21.0/bin/pg_config
sh: 1: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/0.21.0/bin/pg_config: not found

Comment: sh: 1: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/0.21.0/bin/pg_config: not found
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***